# Vector creation fail

Tags: qgis, vector, error, windows-10

I am attempting to create a new vector/SHP polygon layer in a project that was created with QGIS 3.22. After creating the fields I want, then clicking "OK," I get a red warning that the vector creation failed. In the layer name field, ".shp" is added, even though I didn't type it.

The polygon layer is simple: a few vertices to outline a property boundary. I am trying to add Text, Whole Number, and Decimal fields using the default settings of UTF-8 and EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.

Might this be a glitch in the new stable version?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I guess your problem is related to the path of the file you're trying to create. Instead of typing the name directly in the name box, open the folders viewer and select one that you can easily access.